# ColumnText and HTML with Image Base64 tag

Tags: base64, itext, html-to-pdf

I am using [this example](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-add-html-headers-and-footers-page) to show HTML Header and HTML Footer.

But when the html has an image element (base64) does not work.

I tried [another example](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/xml-worker-itext5/html-images). But that does not make use of ColumnText.

I tried add

```
htmlContext.setImageProvider(new Base64ImageProvider());
```

or

```
TagProcessorFactory htmlTagProcessorFactory = Tags.getHtmlTagProcessorFactory();
htmlTagProcessorFactory.removeProcessor(HTML.Tag.IMG);
htmlTagProcessorFactory.addProcessor(new ImageTagProcessor(), HTML.Tag.IMG);
```

But none of the attempts succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make it work. But with Table. In that way the base64 image appears in the PDF document

```
    //CSS
    CSSResolver cssResolver = XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().getDefaultCssResolver(true);

    // HTML
    TagProcessorFactory htmlTagProcessorFactory = Tags.getHtmlTagProcessorFactory();
    //htmlTagProcessorFactory.removeProcessor(HTML.Tag.IMG);
    //htmlTagProcessorFactory.addProcessor(new ImageTagProcessor(), HTML.Tag.IMG);

    HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(null);
    htmlContext.setTagFactory(htmlTagProcessorFactory);
    htmlContext.setImageProvider(new Base64ImageProvider());

    // Pipelines
    ElementList elements = new ElementList();
    ElementHandlerPipeline end = new ElementHandlerPipeline(elements, (Pipeline) null);

    HtmlPipeline htmlPipeline = new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, end);
    CssResolverPipeline css = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, htmlPipeline);

    // XML Worker
    XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(css, true);
    XMLParser p = new XMLParser(worker);
    p.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(html.getBytes()));

    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);

    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
    cell.setPadding(0);
    cell.setUseBorderPadding(false);
    cell.setBorder(0);

    for (Element e : elements) {
        cell.addElement(e);
    }

    table.addCell(cell);

    // Adding a table at an absolute position
    table.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, x, y, writer.getDirectContent());
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the same example you did, I got it working without the need of tables, only ColumnText. You just have to add each element to the ColumnText object, shown at the bottom.

```
    // step 3
    document.open();
    // step 4
    PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
    ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(canvas);
    int side_of_the_page = 0;
    ct.setSimpleColumn(COLUMNS[side_of_the_page]);
    ct.setIgnoreSpacingBefore(false);

   // CSS
   CSSResolver cssResolver = XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().getDefaultCssResolver(true);

   // ELEMENT
   ElementList elements = new ElementList();
   ElementHandlerPipeline end = new ElementHandlerPipeline(elements, (Pipeline) null);

   // HTML
   HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(null);
   htmlContext.setTagFactory(Tags.getHtmlTagProcessorFactory());
   htmlContext.setImageProvider(new Base64ImageProvider());

   // Pipelines
   HtmlPipeline html = new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, end);
   CssResolverPipeline css = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, html);

   // XML Worker
   XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(css, true);
   XMLParser p = new XMLParser(worker);
   p.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(HTML.getBytes()));

   for (Element element : elements) {
         ct.addElement(element);
   }

   // step 5
   document.close();
```